# Getting id's of particular class and storing it in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, class, each

I wanted to save all the id's with the class inactive in an array , then i want to itereate through the array and check for particular values , for instance the inactive ids will be like : menu-level-0-0-1 , menu-level-0-0-2, menu-level-0-1-3
I want to save all these id's and then split it like:

```
        var inactiveID = $('.inactive').attr('id')

        var splitInactive = inactiveID.split('-');
        var inactiveParentCategoryid = splitInactive[3];
        var inactiveCategoryid = splitInactive[4];
```

After splitting it do some checking and if the check pass add the class:

```
if (parentCategoryid == inactiveCategoryid) {
            //$('.menu-level-0-0-'+ inactiveCategoryid).css('background-image', 'url(/Themes/DarkOrange/Content/images/cat-ul-active.png)');
          $('.inactive ').css('color', 'white !Important');
        }
```

The active ids will only be one , thats why i dont need an array and can easily be accessible by :

```
 var activeId = $('.active').attr('id')
        var split = activeId.split('-');
        var parentCategoryid = split[3];
        var categoryid = split[4];
```

Can any one help me in sorting out this issue in a correct way or any other suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems odd to store the hierarchy levels inside your id. Why don't you use classes for this? class="level1", class="level2", etc. Then getting everything in a particular level would be straightforward.

Comment: @mrtsherman I'm curious about the choice in general, too. But assuming there IS a particular reason, IDs will work fine since each value will be unique. And if there's heavy DOM manipulation to be done based on those selections, performance will be higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `.each()`

```
var activeId = new Array();
$('.active').each(function(){
   var currentId = this.id;
   var splitedId = currentId.split('-');
   activeId.push($(this).id); 
});
```

Comment: this.id is much more succinct

Comment: how can i split and match it?

Comment: var inactiveId = new Array();
                    $('.inactive').each(function () {
                       var currentId = $(this).id;
                       var splitedId = currentId.split('-');
                        if (parentCategoryid == splitedId[3]) {
                    $('.menu-level-0-0-'+ inactiveCategoryid).css('background-image', 'url(/Themes/DarkOrange/Content/images/cat-ul-active.png)');
                    $('.inactive ').css('color', 'white !Important');
                }}
                      inactiveId.push($(this).id);
            
        }); tried this doesnt works

Answer (score 4):

[The `map` function](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is well suited to this task:

```
    var items = $('.iactive').map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
```

`items` is now an array.